# Create printer localport from a network printer in windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, network-share, glassfish

I'm having a problem to install a printer using localport,
The printer is installed on a pc with windows 7 and I need to install it in another PC with Windows 2008 R2 creating a new localport for the network printer 
but when I create the port tells me "access denied", the pc with widnows 7 has an simple account with no password and all permissions assigned to the printer (If I install the network printer from the IP, without localport, it print fine)

I need to install the printer using localport because I need to print from a java web using glassfish and also I need not have to create a user account with password in windows 7

How I can do this?

Comment: By "localport" do you mean like LPT1, etc?

Comment: i mean creating a new localport that point to \\192.168.1.104\HPLaserJ, for example, when i install the network printer locally. link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this even as a non-administrator: `net use lpt1 \\192.168.1.104\HPLaserJ`. This will map the printer to your LPT1 port.

If you just want a regular install of a network printer, browse to \192.168.1.104, right-click the printer and choose "Connect".

If this fails, then you have a sharing permissions issue. Check your event logs for details.

Comment: net use work, but glassfish still don't see the printer. this port only work in the current user? i need that the created port works for all user, like a locally installed printer. thx

Comment: Current user yes unfortunately. If this isn't working you'd need to investigate why the denied access is occurring.

Comment: the denied access is occurring because the admin user is disabled on the pc with windows 7 and simple file sharing is enabled. i set the admin account to enabled and set a password for it and everything is working now - thx